# How to change rupee symbol

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Hiii

I am using magento 1.4,I want to change indian currency symbol Rs with new rupee symbol on frontend as well as backend.

Anyone Can tell me about this???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957035/how-to-change-magento-currency-symbol-from-rs-to-indian-rupee-symbol check here... I described in details..

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong the symbol definitions can be found into

```
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/characters.xml
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml
```

If you change those values then copy those files to your local code-pool

```
app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data/characters.xml
app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml
```

when done don't forget to clear cache

`rm -rf var/cache/*`

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your magento root directory and open lib/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml

after that add the symbol = amp#8377;(& for amp) or amp#x20B9;(& for amp) in the following block

```
<currency type="INR">

<symbol> &#x20B9; </symbol>

</currency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For magento 2.2.5 version, to display rupees symbol, add Roboto font family 
and update font-family in css file
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto

```
<style>
@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';src:url(path_of_font/roboto-regular-webfont.woff) format('woff'),url(path_of_font/roboto-regular-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');}

body{color:#333;font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue','Helvetica','Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;line-height:1.42857143;font-size:1.4rem}
</style>

<symbol>&#8377;</symbol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Login to your magento admin panel and follow the below steps

1.System->Configuration->Currency setup

in Currency options tap change all the fields to indian rupee, but the 'Base Currency' is important to change

2.Save the changes

3.Again go to System->Manage Currency->Symbols

in that window shows the default rupee symbols, you just type &#8377 (and put semicolon ; at end) in the Symbol column and uncheck the 'use default' at last and save the changes.

Now go to your user page it will show the rupee symbol. It will work for me in magento 1.9