# How to add rupee symbol to magento

Tags: php, magento, special-characters, currency, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change rupee symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708967/how-to-change-rupee-symbol)

I want to change the default Dollar symbol in magento.
How to add rupee symbol to magento currency symbol?Is there any solution for this.

Comment: refer this links..http://indianicorange.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/how-to-add-new-indian-rupee-symbol-in-currency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below character encode should work in `magento` to display `Indian Rupee sign`.

`&#8377 = ₹`

`&#8360; = ₨`

i.e. `&#8377 1,300` displays `₹ 1,300`.

Reference for changing Currency symbols  [Change Currency Symbol(s) In magento](http://magentocoders.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-change-currency-symbol-in.html)

Comment: could you please tell me exactly where should I use these encode.I am a beginner for magento. Thanks

Comment: Check reference added in answer for further details!